# Make json easily readable (R)

Tags: json, r

Suppose I have a variable `ouput` which contains a json of the form:

```
{"hello1":["bla1"],"hello2":["bla2"],"hello3":{"hello31":{"hello311":[7078],"hello312":[3429]},"hello32":{"hello321":[10],"hello322":[6]},"hello33":{"hello331":[4.6317],"hello332":[2.6322]}}}
```

What can I do to transform `ouput` such as it can be easily readable? I would like something like this:

```
hello1 : bla1
hello2 : bla2
hello3 :
         hello31 : hello311 : 7078
                   hello312 : 3429
         hello32 : hello321 : 10
                   hello322 : 6
         hello33 : hello331 : 4.6317
                   hello332 : 2.6322
```

Comment: Check this website. Seems to do a good job on formatting json. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com.

Comment: Yes I know this website, but I'd like it to be done within my code. I found something not too bad using list.tree from Hmisc which I modified a bit. Nevertheless, if someone knows how to come up with the result I am looking for, I'm very interested! Thanks all for your answers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to inspect the `json`, you could use the package `listviewer`, which renders a nice widget in RStudio.

```
# install.packages("listviewer")

output <- '{"hello1":["bla1"],"hello2":["bla2"],"hello3":{"hello31":{"hello311":[7078],"hello312":[3429]},"hello32":{"hello321":[10],"hello322":[6]},"hello33":{"hello331":[4.6317],"hello332":[2.6322]}}}'

listviewer::jsonedit(output)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'd like to be able to send the output to someone once it is transformed...But thanks for this information!

Answer (score 0):

You can get something similar to your output using the `prettify` function in `jsonlite`.

```
# Your object
my_json_object <- '{"hello1":["bla1"],"hello2":["bla2"],"hello3":{"hello31":{"hello311":[7078],"hello312":[3429]},"hello32":{"hello321":[10],"hello322":[6]},"hello33":{"hello331":[4.6317],"hello332":[2.6322]}}}'


prettify(my_json_object, indent = 2)
{
"hello1": [
    "bla1"
],
"hello2": [
    "bla2"
],
"hello3": {
    "hello31": {
        "hello311": [
            7078
        ],
        "hello312": [
            3429
        ]
    },
    "hello32": {
        "hello321": [
            10
        ],
        "hello322": [
            6
        ]
    },
    "hello33": {
        "hello331": [
            4.6317
        ],
        "hello332": [
            2.6322
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I would need something "cleaner"